# Does every trader set a different value per each item?

Tags: baldurs-gate, baldurs-gate-tutu

I want to sell items, and I wonder if items have different values per trader or per any zone of the map.

I'm playing Baldur's Gate 1, using the Easytutu mod.

Answer (score 4):

The price of an item depends on how many of that item the merchant has in stock.  If the stock is below a certain threshold, you get the "list price"; as the stock goes up, the purchase price (but not the sale price) goes down.

Note that the price only changes after you click the "sell" button.  If you've got a lot of something to sell, give them all to one character, highlight them all, and sell them in a single transaction.

Occasionally you'll find a merchant who pays a fixed price for a limited set of items (eg. Officer Vai's purchase of bandit scalps), but these are uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Zone, most traders set their own prices.  I noticed those those running with The Merchant Guild have the same prices.